# Magento 2 - Show cart quantity without decimals

Tags: magento2, cart

I have to show the total quantity of the items in the cart. I'm doing this now with:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
$totalQuantity = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

echo $totalQuantity;
```

I have 5 items in the cart and the $totalQuantity will show 5.0000 Why is that? And how can I just display 5?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo round($totalQuantity);
```

PHP built in function round() will do the job.

Comment: AWESOOOOOMEEEEE! :)